# Сatching exceptions from paramiko

Tags: python, exception, paramiko

I want to create some logic that will catch some exceptions from the `paramiko` moduleю

I want to create some logic that catches the exception when the wrong password is entered but I am not sure how to do so with a library that isn't from the standard library

```
   try:
      ssh.connect(host, password = "wrongpassword")
   except _____ as e:
      print error msg
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 273, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 456, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

I am not sure how to create an exception for this type of error message. 
I looked others code and it usually contains built-in exceptions --> https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
```

assuming you've imported paramiko.
Exceptions are just objects in python, you can pass them around.

Any exception contains various information about it's class, the state of the system and where it was raised. The simplest thing you can do is

```
print e
```

which will give you the message with which the exception was created.

Comment: How would I print this message? Specifically the Authentication failed portion. Would `e` be the `Authentication failed.` message?

Comment: @Liondancer depends on how they have implemented the exception class. Generally `e` should be `Authentication failed` if not, the `Authentication failed` message should in `e.args`. So `print e` or `print e.args` should give you that message